# boost::compute copy custom structures

Tags: boost-compute

Is it possible to copy arrays of custom structures using boost::compute? E.g.

```
struct A { float a; };
struct AB { float a; float b; };

BOOST_COMPUTE_ADAPT_STRUCT(A, A, (a))
BOOST_COMPUTE_ADAPT_STRUCT(AB, AB, (a, b))

boost::compute::vector<A> va(100);
boost::compute::vector<AB> vab(100);
boost::compute::copy(va.begin(), va.end(), vab.begin());
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, look at [this example](https://github.com/boostorg/compute/blob/master/test/test_struct.cpp#L64) from Boost.Compute tests. Remember that:

> Due to differences in struct padding between the host compiler and the
>   device compiler, the BOOST_COMPUTE_ADAPT_STRUCT() macro requires that
>   the adapted struct is packed (i.e. no padding bytes between members).

Source: [boost/compute/types/struct.hpp](https://github.com/boostorg/compute/blob/master/include/boost/compute/types/struct.hpp#L127)

Comment: I see I can copy arrays of same structures, from array of structure to POD array. But I don't see how I can copy arrays of different structures. Is the only way to write your own boost compute function to convert one struct to another?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for not understanding your question... Now when I look at this code I think it's impossible to copy vectors of different structures using just `boost::compute::copy()`. I think it should be possible to copy them using `boost::compute::transform()` and passing a custom boost compute function which converts one to the another.

Comment: Thanks @haahh, probably custom function is a way to go. Somewhat difficult if your types are templates though.

Comment: You should be able to create a function template which produced custom Boost.Compute function based on the template parameters. See [test_function.cpp#L160](https://github.com/boostorg/compute/blob/master/test/test_function.cpp#L160).